# Talking to a serial device - find out the language

Tags: linux, serial

**Question:**

I have an RS232 console connected to a Raspberry Pi 3 via USB.

I can see that it in `/dev/ttyUSB0`

How can I talk to it without knowing what are the right commands? Is there even a way?

I know I am pretty much asking if a Chinese can speak to an American assuming non of em knows the other's language, but all I am looking for are basically 2 commands.

- Note - My Linux skill level is really low.

---

**Context:**

I have bought a "smart home" system.

They installed 10 electronic cards of 16 switches, connected to an adapter, connected to a serial cable, connected to a serial-to-USB connected to a Linux machine.

The machine sent 2 types of commands:

- what is the status of all cards and switches?
- change status of a card switch (card number, switch number, on/off)

The Linux machine SSD died. No chance of data recovery.

To install a new machine they require 2 grand, and I am not inclined to pay. I want to interface the cards by myself. (so ill use apple homekit)

**Image for clarification:**
[image]
Cards ---------> adapter ----------------------------------------------> cable -> rs232 to usb -> computer

Comment: No warranty on this system?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-linux-serial-ports-with-setserial/

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I did. I tried to work with minicom, and screen, and got no where. I still don't know how to talk to the device with something it will understand

Comment: And you do not think that depends on the device?

Comment: That's a Texas Instruments USB/Serial chip; I've worked on tons of devices like these (embedded using RS232/USB/Ethernet). Chances are it uses the [Hayes communication set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) (also known as AT commands). It's hard to see the serial number printed on the TI chip in your picture, but there's a high probability that you can plug that into google with "AT" appended and get the command descriptions you might be able to send to it. Essentially, you're bit-banging the device until it responds. Most systems like these are wide open (security is expensive)

Comment: It looks to me that a cheap on this board is just a voltage level converter (5 or 12 volts to/from 3.3volt). It looks also that they use "3 wire" serial (Rx,Tx,GND) only. Kinda strange to drive multiple slave cards over RS232. While it possible to hook multiple devices on a single RS232 line but it kinda non professional since RS232 is p2p protocol. Usually RS422/485 used for such communications. Could you take more sharp picture of the chip or just tell us its name, I see there MAX.... something

Comment: @Alex Did you open the image? (better resolution). I don't see any "MAX" actually, can you point where that is so ill take a better picture of that?

Comment: It is the chip that marked on PCB as `U2`

Answer (score 0):

What about using cutecom - the simple graphics serial port terminal for listening on the serial port? It may be easyer than using minicom or screen.